# Isolated/noisy instances that have outsized effect on SVM hyperplane selection

Tags: svm, noise

Consider two linearly separable classes and the optimal separating hyperplane (image credit Prof Jiawei Han of UIUC):

[image]

Now consider if there were a single "rogue" point for the Yellow class - which may or may not be noise - and the effect it has on the corresponding optimal separating hyperplane (shown in red):

[image]

Is there a modified version of SVM to allow for this situation - to "consider" the isolated observation when calculating the hyperplane but not be strictly driven by it?  Would this be a case of using *slack variables*  - as shown in this slide (credit: CS @ CMU https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/slides/Kernels_SVM2_04_12_2011-ann.pdf)  ?

[image]

Is this problem - which is to say

> some observations may be noisy and we should not put too much weight on any individual one

the same one as

> instances of the two classes are not linearly separable

If not then would there be a different approach to representing this *svm with noise* then using *slack variables* ?